# Is it safe to install ubuntu natty daily build beside maverick?

Tags: 11.04

Recently I decided to test **natty**, so i download it and try to install it on VirtualBox *(v4.0 - 3D Acceleration Enabled)* but have problem in using unity *(It says to change my desktop to classic...)*
Now I want to install it on my PC, so I came here to ask is it safe to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!

It's safe when you resize your partition to have about 20 to 30 GB unused space. 
Then you install from scratch using this unused space, leaving your system untouched. Just don't mess up your partition names during this process.
If done right you'll get a dual boot system that way!

There should be an option within the installer to resize your partition during the install process if you start the installer from the live cd. Be careful when the bootmanager (grub) gets it's entries, not to mess it up. But even this would be easy to fix afterwards.

BUT:

If you are not familiar with the install process I STRONGLY advise to try the whole procedure of the parallel installation on your Virtualbox disk (the one you already have a natty system running on) BEFORE running on your productive system! 
Also remeber: Natty is still alpha status, so I would suggest a test run on a virtualbox disk in any case!

Good Luck, Have Fun!

cya, piedro

Comment: -1: What makes you so sure, that a buggy application wouldn't be able to screw up data in the other partitions?

Comment: Well, you're theoretically right but it's very unlikely that an application (talking about standard programs) working in one partition is messing up another one. So the risk lies in the partition resizer (parted?), right? And plz note that's why I strongly suggest a test run of a parallel install on a virtual machine. I don't get your point.

Comment: If you have some insight in some known risk involved plz let us know! Thx, piedro

Comment: The only thing problem I had was easily fixed - I ran 'sudo apt-get upgrade` this morning and had my 10.10 install disappear from the grub menu. I mounted the 10.10 partition and ran 'sudo update-grub` and the problem was fixed. That just goes to show you that if you don't know what might (or might not) be causing something, then you probably shouldn't be screwing around with Natty *at this point* - by the time we hit Alpha 2, it'll be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I think the idea was not to upgrade but rather to make a fresh install - just hosted on the same computer ... without screwing up the other OS (maverick in this case) ...

Comment: the only problem I have is grub! when natty installed grub list was ok but maverick was not the default OS (while I select maverick to be default during natty installation, but I'm not so sure), so I do `sudo grub-install --recheck --root-directory=/media/maverick /dev/sda` in natty, and reboot. but grub didn't run and said "arguments are not set" or something like that. and now I haven't access to natty by grub!

Comment: Sry benzadesh, I didN_t see your comment until now... hope you fixed it. IF not yet I recommend the rescatux boot cd, you can fix everything with that: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/